# Entity Framework: Code First - Column Mapping

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a model like this:

```
public class Entity
{
    [Key, Required]
    public virtual long EntityId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual long? ParentEntityId { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my table:

```
create table Entities(
    EntityId bigint not null identity(1, 1),
    Name nvarchar(64) not null,
    ParentEntityId bigint null
)
```

ParentEntityId is a foreign key to EntityId.

When I try to create a Entity entity this is the exception I get:
`Invalid column name 'ParentEntity_EntityId'.`

I don't know why EF is picking that *convention* for that particular column, but if I do this:

```
[Column("TryPickThisName")]
public virtual int? ParentEntityId { get; set; }
```

The same error shows up with "TryPickThisName" column name. And finally if I write the column name correctly **or** remove the attribute it will show the *original* error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you leave part of your model out?

I think what is happening is you're wanting to create a self referencing table, with Entity optionally referring to itself if it has a ParentEntity.

What's happening is EF is creating the ParentEntity_EntityId because you didn't explicitly map the FK property to the navigation property.  Adding a ForeignKey data annotation will correct this.

```
public class Entity
{
    [Key, Required]
    public virtual long EntityId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentEntity")]
    public virtual long? ParentEntityId { get; set; }
    public virtual Entity ParentEntity { get; set; }
}
```

Creates this database:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've added the attribute and it works.

Comment: My understanding was that the virtual keyword was for the entity and lazy loading.  I notice it is on the key here, perhaps unnecessarily?  Some purpose I'm not aware of, obviously.